Using InTheHand / Feet32 Bluetooth in VB Net
I am trying to attach to a bluetooth device using Windows 10, VB Net (Community 2022) with the InTheHand nuget package
Imports InTheHand.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth

Public Class Form1
    Dim cbluetoothClient = BluetoothClient()
End Class

The error I am getting is:
BC30560 'BluetoothClient' is ambiguous in the namespace 'InTheHand.Net.Sockets'.
What do I need to qualify the name?
I have 32Feet.Net installed (Ver 3.50)
I have InTheHand.net.bluetooth installed (Ver 4.14)
I am trying to list all bluetooth devices, and have the user select one, then connect, and just capture the data from the device.
A sample would help a lot.
Any help is appreciated. TIA
--alan
I tried removing 32feet.net and InTheHand, 1 at a time, and it didn't help.
I tried InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothComponent.BluetoothClient and other things offered by Intellisense, but that got me nowhere, the error remained.
I tried
Dim BC = New InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevicePicker BC.PickSingleDeviceAsync(), but I'm not sure what to do next to connect the device.

Your project imports two namespaces, both of which expose a BluetoothClient() definition.
Imports InTheHand.Net.Sockets
...
Imports InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth

Use either
Public Class Form1
    Dim cbluetoothClient = InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient()
End Class

or
Public Class Form1
    Dim cbluetoothClient = InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothClient()
End Class

to specify which class to use.

I removed the imports of 32feet
Now,
BC30456 'BluetoothClient' is not a member of 'InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth'
for line: Dim cbluetoothClient = InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothClient()
Intellisense only shows the following (Starting with bluetooth) for InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth
BluetoothDevicePicker, BluetoothProtocol, BluetoothRadio, Bluetoothsecurity, BluetoothService, BluetoothVersion

Do you have any other suggestions?

@Alan I don't understand why you did that and it's not what I recommended in my answer.
